# Cannot find sources of WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 patch SP1

Tags: wso2, identity, patch

does anyone know where can I find sources for WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0 - Service Pack 1? That SVN WSO2 repository is very complex. And there's no clue where to look for it.

According the "help page" [Building from source WSO2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Building+from+Source)

Sources should be somewhere here [SVN repository - WSO2 Carbon Core 4.2.0](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/)

Thank you,

Josef

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i know, SP1 source is not currently available in a separate public palace. But all these source have been added in to the next version of Identity Server release.  But these sources may not be completely match with the SP1 source. If you are finding next version source.. It is also not in a common place, you can find most of the identity related source from [here](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/identity/).  You can browse the desired component and find the highest version of it. Then it would be the latest source for next release.

Comment: So SP1 was released, but sources are not available to the public? What a shame. So when it is going to be released new version of Identity Server? Is it going to be 5.1.0 ? Will sources be available for this version?

Comment: Yes.. it is.  It may be 5.1.0... Source is already available as i mentioned in above comment.

Comment: Thank you Asela, I will try to cope with that.

Comment: Has the source code for the 5 version been released anywhere? is there any other way to access 5.0+ version of the identity server?

Comment: The 5.1.0 sources are different from the 5.0.0.SP1, so effectively we're unable to pinpoint some exceptions :/ Migrating to 5.1.0 can be painful with customized userstores or authenticators